# PipedInputStream / PipedOutputStream, ImageIO and ffmpeg

Tags: scala, amazon-ec2, ffmpeg, pipe, javax.imageio

I have the following code in Scala:

```
      val pos = new PipedOutputStream()
      val pis = new PipedInputStream(pos)

      Future {
        LOG.trace("Start rendering")
        generateFrames(videoRenderParams.length) {
          img ⇒ ImageIO.write(img, "PNG", pos)
        }
        pos.flush()
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(pos)
        LOG.trace("Finished rendering")
      } onComplete {
        case Success(_) ⇒ 
          LOG.trace("Complete successfully")
        case Failure(err) ⇒
          LOG.error("Can't render stuff", err)
          IOUtils.closeQuietly(pis)
          IOUtils.closeQuietly(pos)
      }

      val prc = (ffmpegCli #< pis).!(logger)
```

the Future simply writes the generated images one by one to the **OutputStream**. Now the **ffmpeg** process reads the input images from **stdin** and converts them to MP4 file.

That works pretty well, but for some reason sometimes I'm getting the following stacktraces:

```
I/O error Pipe closed for process: <input stream>
java.io.IOException: Pipe closed
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.checkStateForReceive(PipedInputStream.java:260)
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.receive(PipedInputStream.java:226)
    at java.io.PipedOutputStream.write(PipedOutputStream.java:149)
    at scala.sys.process.BasicIO$.loop$1(BasicIO.scala:236)
    at scala.sys.process.BasicIO$.transferFullyImpl(BasicIO.scala:242)
    at scala.sys.process.BasicIO$.transferFully(BasicIO.scala:223)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessImpl$PipeThread.runloop(ProcessImpl.scala:159)
    at scala.sys.process.ProcessImpl$PipeSource.run(ProcessImpl.scala:179)
```

At the same time I'm getting the following error from another stream:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: I/O error writing PNG file!
    at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageWriter.write(PNGImageWriter.java:1168)
    at javax.imageio.ImageWriter.write(ImageWriter.java:615)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.doWrite(ImageIO.java:1612)
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(ImageIO.java:1578)
    at
```

So it seems that the streams were broken somewhere in between, so **ffmpeg** can not read the data, and **ImageIO** can not write the data.

What is even more interesting - the problem is reproducible only on certain Linux server (Amazon). It works flawlessly on other Linux boxes. So I wonder if somebody could point me out to  the possible causes of this error.

What I've tried so far:

- use Oracle JDK 8 and OpenJDK
- use different versions of FFMPEG

Nothing worked by the moment.

Comment: What is the `ExecutionContext` you are using to run the `Future`?

Comment: ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was kind of predictable and weird at the same time. So there were ten concurrent **ffmpeg** processes scheduled to handle the input, and the input was a set of hundreds of **FullHD** pictures. Obviously that takes lot of computation capacity, hence the kernel randomly shut down **ffmpeg** processes, causing Java wrapper to report broken input and output pipe at the same time.

Thus **/var/log/messages** contained many of logs like below:

```
Out of memory: Kill process 25778 (java) score 159 or sacrifice child
Killed process 25931 (ffmpeg) total-vm:2337040kB, anon-rss:966340kB, file-rss:104kB
```

Reducing the number of concurrent **ffmpeg** processes solved the issue.